# Usage of constructors in scala

Tags: scala

There seems to be no reason and/or possibility to define a default constructor in scala.

Basically, does the concept of the constructor not exist because everything constructor-related is wrote in the class body?

```
class SeriousClass {
    exmpl: Text = new Text

    runMethod()
}
```

The only reason I can think of is to define a `default constructor` in addition to the parametered one, or a parametered one in addition to the default constructor.

```
class SeriousClass2(param: Param) {
    def this() {
        this(new Param())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default constructor **does exists** and yes, it's whole body of class. Instead of writing

```
class SeriousClass2(param: Param) {
    def this() {
        this(new Param())
    }
}
```

You would be better to just provide default value for default constructor:

```
class SeriousClass2(param: Param = new Param()) {

}
```

It is both idiomatic and more readable.

Moreover, sometimes you may want to prohibit class instantiation from the outside. This may be archived with specifying constructor scope:

```
class PrettyPrivateClass private() {

}
```

Comment: So, there is basically no reason to ever `def this()`, right?

Comment: Given the fact that the primary constructor _must_ be called, secondary / auxiliary constructors can only be written in terms of the primary constructor (or other secondary constructors). Thus there is a single code path that is shared by all constructors and there is not as much freedom to create arbitrarily varied constructors. Additionally, the first thing any secondary constructor must do is call another constructor. All in all, it's much more constrained than, say, Java.